something wierd is happening with my background in css
<!-- html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

/* CSS */

body {
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue);

}

enter image description here
my output
i am learing about gradient background in css. why is this gradient being repeated multiple times. as it should only color the whole body of the page in just one go without any repetition like this.
enter image description here expected output
Hope you understand what i am trying to explain. I am new in this :)

your problem is caused by the fact your body height is equal to line height.

@GottZ I looked for more answers and I found out that if i use fixed keyword the gradiewnt effect stretches for complete viewport. But i have a question, do i have to use fixed keyword everytime to tackle this problem?
code:
body {
background: linear-gradient(red, orange) fixed;
}
